# Radon-Nikodym derivative of harmonic measure against surface measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, radon-nikodym

Let $B_t$ be $d$-dim Brownian motion. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain and denote by $\tau_U = \inf\{t \mid B_t\notin U\}$ the exit time.
For $x \in U$ and $A \subset \partial U$ let $\mu_{\partial U}^x (A)= \mathbb{P}^x(B_{\tau_{\partial U}}\in A)$ be the harmonic measure on $\partial U$.
I have two questions:

1. If $\sigma$ denotes the surface measure on $\partial U$, then there exists a Radon Nikodym derivative $f_{\partial U}^x= \frac{d\mu_{\partial U}^x}{d \sigma}$ such that
   $$\mu_{\partial U}^x(A) = \int_A f_{\partial U}^x(y) d\sigma$$ for any measurable $A \subset \partial U$. This follows by the Radon Nikodym theorem. Is that correct?
2. What do we know about $f$? Are there any explicit formulae or is it possible to show that $f$ is bounded? In my case I would need an $L^2$ estimate, i.e. an upper bound for $\lVert f_{\partial U}^x\rVert_{\partial U}$. Does anybody have an idea  for this? Or a good reference?

Comment: (1) you need to know that $d\mu_{\partial U}^x \ll d\sigma$ (maybe I wrote that the wrong way), i.e. $\sigma(E) = 0$ implies $d\mu_{\partial U}^x(E) = 0$. I'm pretty sure this is true for your setup. (2) How can you ask for an explicit formula if you don't say what $U$ is?

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for your comments! (1) Yes I also think that the absolute continuity is given in this case. So the first question is fine. (2) I was hoping that it is e.g. possible to show that $f$ is bounded and/or $\lVert f_{\partial U}^x\rVert_{\partial U}$ is finite for a general bounded domain $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: $f$ not being bounded is equivalent to $\mu_{\partial U}^x(A)$ being arbitrarily multiplicatively larger than $\sigma(A)$ (as $A$ ranges). I don't think this will be the case (i.e. I think $f$ will be bounded), but I'm not sure. seems interesting to me. in any event, I'm sure there are references on this stuff.

Comment: @mathworker21 Good point, however intuitively I would guess that $\frac{\mu_{\partial U}^x}{\sigma}$ is unbounded which would mean that $f$ is unbounded. I will think about this and maybe somebody will add more information.

Comment: I think for *fixed $x$* $\frac{\mu^x_{\partial U}}{\sigma}$ will be bounded. But let's agree to disagree until someone either finds a reference or provides a proof.

Comment: @mathworker21 Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Considering the question whether $\frac{\mu^x_{\partial U}}{\sigma}$ is bounded I think I already found a case where this is not true, namely when $U$ is the unit ball. 
Observe the following statement, copied from *Durrett - Brownian motion and martingales in Analysis, p. 36*,
[image]

where $D$ is the unit sphere.

If I am not misunderstanding things, this shows that in this case $\frac{\mu^x_{\partial U}}{\sigma} = \frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^d}$ (up to some multiplicative constant, since $\nu$ is normalized), which is not bounded.
Hence, in general, $\frac{\mu^x_{\partial U}}{\sigma}$ is not bounded. Right?

Comment: how is that not bounded? I even took the time to emphasize before that $x$ is fixed here.

Comment: @mathworker21 My apologies, I totally missed the fact that $x= y$ is not possible...

Comment: no problem. my intuition is as follows, by the way. fix some $x$ in the unit disk. then an arc near $x$ will be more likely to first be hit than its proportion of length would suggest; however, that increase in likelihood doesn't get arbitrarily large as the arc shrinks.

Comment: I guess that's more of me restating the result than intuition why it's true, but whatever. It's how I think about the situation

Comment: @mathworker21 I understand your thinking. I guess this is a helpful approach on how to look at the problem. Perhaps someone will find a way to make the statement rigorously.

Comment: once again, im nearly certain someone has. just find the appropriate reference